# Magento 2.4.3 custom module enable/disable functionality not working

Tags: magento2.4.3

I have created a custom module, I have added custom module enable/disable functionality from the admin panel,

but it's not working properly, if I've disabled the module then also content display at the front-end,

here is the code that I have tried.

syetm.xml file add custom filed for module configuration **system.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="ncode" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Share Cart</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="wpsharecart" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Share Cart</label>
            <tab>ncode</tab>
            <resource>Ncode_Wpsharecart::wpsharecart_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                    <field id="enablesharecart" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>WhatsApp Share Cart Enable</label>
                        <comment><![CDATA[Select Yes to enable Whatsapp Cart module on cart page.]]></comment>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    </field>

                    <field id="button_label_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Button Label Text</label>  
                        <validate>required-entry</validate> 
                        <depends>
                            <field id="enablesharecart">1</field>
                        </depends>                      
                    </field>

                    <field id="cart_message_on_wp_share" translate="label" type="textarea" sortOrder="31" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Cart Message on Whatsapp Share Link</label>   
                        <validate>required-entry</validate>    
                        <depends>
                            <field id="enablesharecart">1</field>
                        </depends>                  
                    </field>

                    <field id="wp_button_position" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="32" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Whatsapp Button Position on Cart Page</label>
                        <comment><![CDATA[select button position for display on cart page]]></comment>
                         <source_model>Ncode\Wpsharecart\Model\Label\Source\Position</source_model>
                        <depends>
                            <field id="enablesharecart">1</field>
                        </depends>
                    </field>
                    <!-- <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                        <label>Display Text</label>
                        <comment>This text will display on the frontend.</comment>
                    </field> -->
            </group>
  </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

custom helper to check module enable / disable based on system configuration **Data.php**

```
<?php
namespace Ncode\Wpsharecart\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{    
    const MODULE_ENABLE = "wpsharecart/general/enable";   

    public function getDefaultConfig($path)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue($path, 
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    }

    public function isModuleEnabled()
    {
        return (bool) $this->getDefaultConfig(self::MODULE_ENABLE);
    }
}
```

**Ncode\Wpsharecart\Block\Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Ncode\Wpsharecart\Block;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Ncode\Wpsharecart\Helper\Data
    */
    protected $_dataHelper;
    /**
      * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
      * @param \Ncode\Wpsharecart\Helper\Data $dataHelper
      * @param array $data
    */

    //  protected $_postFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Ncode\Wpsharecart\Helper\Data $dataHelper, 
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        //$this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
        $this->_dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function canShowBlock()
    {
      return $this->_dataHelper->isModuleEnabled();
    }
    public function getPostCollection(){
        $post = $this->_postFactory->create();
        return $post->getCollection();
    }
}
```

Block to get module configuration value **Ncode/Wpsharecart/view/frontend/templates/onepage/wpbutton.phtml**

```
<?php if ($block->canShowBlock()): ?>
  <h1> My Mdule content </h1>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

**please let me know what should I do mistakes here.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

field id is wrong change that from enable --> enablesharecart

configuration path should match like `sectionid/groupid/fieldid`

Comment: from which file i need to change?

Comment: `const MODULE_ENABLE = "wpsharecart/general/enable";` should be `const MODULE_ENABLE = "wpsharecart/general/enablesharecart";`

Comment: yes..done..its work now..thanks all.